# Query design practices in SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am building queries for a database in MS Access 2007 and I am wondering if my current design practices are up to par. Basically, the database was configured before I came, but I have been given the responsibility of building efficient queries to extract the data.

My current queries are small and simple, each accomplishing 2-3 tasks (sometimes only 1) at a time. The reason I am taking this approach is because I am completely new to SQL, and I find it easier to work with many, simple queries and use reports to consolidate the data, as opposed to building extremely complex queries which are 1) hard to build (for me, anyways) and 2) hard to maintain.

I was just curious if anyone had any best practices for query design, and if you could give me some specific feed back for the approach listed above, and whether or not I should start making complex queries, or just stick to simple queries and reports to consolidate the relevant data.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340796/would-dereferencing-a-foreign-key-in-sql-theoretically-work/6340983#6340983 The buidling block approach or "resusable" doesn't always apply to SQL/queries.

Comment: Are you using reports to avoid using table joins, I wonder?

Comment: @onedaywhen - No, most of my queries are cross tab queries and I'm joining tables through them. But my queries accomplish very specific tasks (2-3 per query), and then I am creating the 'big picture' with the data through the reports. I'm just wondering if this is efficient from a design perspective. The code is more maintainable, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The people answering this question are not coming to it from an Access point of view, so I'll offer some observations as somebody who has been creating Access applications professionally full-time since 1996.

First off, there are several places where you'll have SQL in an Access application:

1. stored queries.
2. stored properties of forms, reports, combo boxes and list boxes.
3. in VBA code where you are writing SQL on the fly.

Managing all of these SQL statements in an organized fashion is difficult, if not impossible. But I'm not sure it's worth it!

First off, consider just stored queries. If you follow the advice of saving a query for every individual task so that each SQL statement is used in only one place, you'll soon have a mess in the list of queries, and you'll be forced into some kind of naming convention to keep track of what's what. Because of this, I generally don't save queries EXCEPT where they MUST be saved, or where the optimization that comes with a saved query is going to be helpful (i.e., large dataset or complex joins/filtering).

For example, when I first started programming in Access, I'd save all the rowsources of my combo boxes as saved queries. I developed a naming convention so they wouldn't be mixed in with the other queries in the list of queries, so it wasn't to hard to manage. At first, I thought I'd be re-using the saved queries, but it quickly became clear that I needed to make changes for individual circumstances, and changing a query that was used elsewhere might alter its results in other contexts, so really, there was no "shared code" benefit to the saved queries (as I thought there would be). The only place where it was helpful was where I had the same combo box on multiple forms, and then I could save the rowsource for that as a saved query and if I needed to alter it, I could it in just one place. However, that was really only an advantage for a relatively complex rowsource -- a simple SELECT on a couple of fields doesn't really benefit from that kind of sharing, particularly when it's used in only a couple of different places.

In short, I quickly concluded that it was just easier to save the SQL statements where they were used -- since there was very little re-use in the first place (once I gained enough experience to realize the pitfalls of trying to re-use them), this worked much better, and it kept the SQL close to where it was being used.

For forms and reports, I do some of the same things, but in general, use saved queries for the purpose of avoiding having to write too many complex subselects for use as derived tables. Where I needed those it was always easier to write it and save it and then use it with a JOIN in another SQL statement than it was to try to use the subselect inline as a derived table (which just makes for complicated SQL that's hard to read -- particularly when you can't comment or format your SQL, as is the case with saved Access queries).

In general, I don't save the recordsources of forms or reports except where there is real re-use going on (a report will often use the same recordsource as a form, so in that case, it's useful to save it, so that when you change the SQL of the form, the report that goes with it inherits the alteration).

That all leaves dynamic SQL assembled in VBA code. I use lots of this, from dynamically setting the rowsources of combo/listboxes, to setting the recordsources of subforms for filtering purposes. This is harder to manage, and sometimes I use string constants in the module to make that easier. For instance, in a case where you're writing dynamic SQL where everything remains the same except the WHERE clause, a constant with the SELECT and a second constant with the ORDER BY makes it a lot easier to assemble the complete SQL statement.

I don't know if this really answers your questions, but I have learned over the years that the benefits of re-using SQL statements are vastly outweighed by the uncertainty that comes from the inability to track easily where that SQL statement may be used. I find that storing the SQL statment as close to where it is used as possible is the best practice, as that is a form of "self-documentation" (though not a great one!).

I do make many exceptions and save queries when there is a real and demonstrable benefit in terms of performance or managing what would otherwise become much more comples SQL. However, I would also note that one should also not go too far in the other direction, using tons of nested saved queries, because then you run into other problems (i.e., the "too many databases" problem, which is actually caused by using up the 2048 table handles available at one time -- it's done more easily than you might think).

Comment: It would be nice if Access let you organize your queries into subfolders in the navigation pane. Oh well. One of the reasons I am building these queries is so that future employees, without any sort of programming knowledge, can query our data without having to touch SQL, VBA, etc. Also, as far as re-use, the queries I am building will all be used on a weekly basis, so I am still tempted to keep several small queries, since your approach seems like it would be best for people who are knowledgeable about Access, and can actually make changes to the underlying SQL.

Comment: For my own personal use, however, I think your approach is a good one.

Comment: I would likely build a UI that allows ad hoc querying and the code behind the UI would write the SQL on the fly and present the results to the user. That way, there's no need to manage a bunch of stored queries.

Comment: Can you write the UI in Access or should I do it with something like python?

Comment: I'm an Access developer, so of course I'd create the UI in Access. What you'd use would depend on your level of accomplishment with the various alternatives, but even if you've never used Access, my bet is that you could create a richer UI for your users using Access than with any other tools, given a limited amount of time.

Comment: @Jerry--When asking about the UI, you're making the common mistake of thinking that Access is a DBMS. It's not--it's a Rapid Application Development platform with a so-so DBMS at its core. If you're storing data in Access, you should _probably_ be doing the UI in Access.

Answer (score 1):

My humble opinion, it doesn't matter if DB engine is big and monstrous as MSSQL or Oracle, or tiny and simple as SQLite, every query (or stored procedure or any other unit of data processing) should be responsible only for 1 function. I use this principle anywhere (not only in DB development) and I can say it works.
If you are not sure, try to read books about refactoring, Fawler for example. I suppose his principles are applicable to any area of development.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing your data in MSAccess then your database cannot be too large and any optimization you do is limited by the constraints MSAccess imposes.  If better (more optimized) queries is a goal, then perhaps migrating the data out of Access and into SQL Server may allow you to have better flexibility in development going forward.  You can leverage cached execution plans, stored procedure, and views.
This may mean that you will need to enhance your T-SQL skills to accomplish this.

So weigh out the options you propose in your question:
 1. Keep code simple (comfortable at your current skill level)
 2. Meet the responsibility to create efficient queries for data extraction.

SQL Server Express could be a good starting point (it's free).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am being forced to use Access 2007. I definitely will keep the code simple though, it's just feels strange to be working with many tiny pieces of code (or queries) as opposed to building a couple of massive queries that could do everything at once.