# Tips for separating query conditions from form names in GUI

Tags: ms-access

I have inherited a rather large set of Access front-ends.  Nearly all of the queries are created with the graphical QBE tool and have the GUI elements hard-coded.  Conceptually a query could be:

```
  SELECT * FROM myTable
  WHERE [Forms]![frm_Main]![frm_TabLine].[Form]![frm_YetAnotherForm].[Form]![SomeId]
```

Having the GUI elements tied to the query logic just feels wrong to me, and is a royal pain when I have to change something in the front-end.  Do you have any recommendations for separating the GUI from the queries?  Especially for large (possibly convoluted) legacy QBE queries.

### 1. For new queries

No problems.  Queries are dynamically created in VBA.  Any changes to GUI names can be handled with search and replace. I found this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414872/query-design-practices-in-sql) helpful.

### 2. Legacy Queries in reports

For a legacy reports I remove the WHERE conditions in the query and specify it in VBA using the optional whereCondition argument

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "SomeReport", acViewPreview, , "GroupNum = " & Me.comboBox1.Value
```

### 3. Legacy Queries

For legacy queries I remove the WHERE condition then dynamically create a query in VBA that looks something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM LegacyQBEQueryNoConditions
WHERE  groupNum = Me.comboBox1.Value
```

I haven't determined if I'm taking a huge performance hit on this, but it still feels like a dirty way to do it.

Does anyone have advice on separating the business logic in the forms from QBE queries that allows GUI elements to be changed with a minimum of pain?  Or are hard-coded paths in QBE queries just a liability that I have to live with?

Comment: Is this question about your third topic heading (Legacy Queries), and the first two topics are more-or-less "problem solved"?  I'm not sure what you're asking.  Maybe it would help for you to describe what feels wrong.

Comment: @Hans yes that's a bit misleading listing something that works.  "Just create the queries dynamically in VBA" seems to be obvious answer so I wanted to address it.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to specifically partition QBE queries from GUI elements.

Comment: I'm still lost on this one.  I almost never save a named query which includes a reference to a data control. In a context where I want a query to reference the value of a data control, I create or modify the query "on the fly".  Works for me, and has for years.  Again, perhaps it would help for you to describe why it feels wrong.

Comment: @Hans " I almost never save a named query which includes a reference to a data control."  I'll take that as a rule then.  I'm new at the msaccess and have only limited GUI experience in other platforms.  I typically write a small CLI program and tie a GUI to it as the last step if I need it.

Comment: Um ... OK.  That's *my* rule for myself.  You're welcome to adopt it for yourself.  :-)  I don't like to "hard-wire" form or control names in queries, and avoid doing that whenever I can.  Also, I should acknowledge I am weird.

Comment: You've encountered an issue of programming style. As @HansUp says, most experienced Access developers won't hardwire references to form controls into their saved SQL statements. In fact, I tend not to save SQL statements that much, in any case -- I save them in the SQL properties of forms and controls and write them dynamically in code. But all of this is a matter of style and experience, not anything specific to Access, which allows you to do all sorts of horrid things (and the sample databases are perfect examples of all sorts of WORST PRACTICES).

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in such case migrate to typed query parameters like described in [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208916%28v=office.12%29.aspx).
So your query will looks like:

```
PARAMETERS [Employee Title] CHAR;
SELECT LastName, FirstName, EmployeeID
FROM Employees
WHERE Title =[EmployeeTitle];
```

And VBA to run it:

```
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("Find Employees")
qdf![EmployeeTitle] = "Sales Manager"
qfd.OpenRecordset...
```